# Hibernate interceptor, onPrepareStatement(),try to "read" the value of the prepared statement SQL string

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

i have a question on the interceptor class of hibernate, i want to read the string of a SQL returned from the method onPrepareStatement of a custom interceptor on hibernate, or read the array of value of the record sql called from a `List<T> list =  criteria.list();` before the invocation of the method "getEntity()" always of the interceptor class, like this:

```
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    System.out.println("onPrepareStatement: Called for statement: " + sql);
    //The SQL in input is like this:
    //onPrepareStatement: Called for statement:     
    //select this_.doc_id as doc_id1_1_0_, this_.city as city2_1_0_

    //for a java object Obj(Integer doc_id,String city);

    //What i want is read->modify->return the SQL to Hibernate:

    //[READ]select "doc_id" as doc_id1_1_0_, "city" as city2_1_0_    
    //[MODIFY]select "doc_id2" as doc_id1_1_0_, "city2" as city2_1_0_
    //[RETURN]select this_.doc_id as doc_id1_1_0_, this_.city as city2_1_0_
    return sql;
}
```

I know is a prepared statement and i can't capture the actual value of the columns, But I have shown this example just to give an idea of what I need to do. 
Ty in advance for any help.